# AWS media forbidden

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku, web-hosting

I get the 403 error when my Heroku app tries to access pictures from my AWS bucket. I followed the Heroku guide on user uploads with Python: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python
and changed it a little so it would only affect user uploads and not my static files. Even though I turned off "block all public access" it is still forbidden

My settings:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('my key')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('my secret key')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my bucket name'

#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'
#DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

if DEBUG == False:
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/'
    # MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    # ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

and here is my CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

but it is copied and pasted directly from Heroku's guide so I doubt it is the problem.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that could cause 403. FYI switching off Block Public Access doesn't magically make objects public. It simply *allows* you to make them public. However, making them public is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Any idea what could cause a 403? I just made it public because everyone in the internet seems to and I don't reallly know what I'm doing lol

Comment: You didn’t make the objects public, at least not by disabling Block Public Access, anyway. 403 is Access Denied, most probably that your credentials do not have permission. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/